# Exist a eigenvector $v=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ such that $x,y >0$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **Problem**: Let $\begin{bmatrix} a &b \\ c&d \end{bmatrix}$ is a real $2 \times 2$  matrix such that $a,b,c,d>0$. Prove that exist a
>   eigenvector $v=\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ such that $x,y
> >0$

I no have ideal for this problem.

Comment: Can you find the two eigenvalues in terms of the matrix elements?

Comment: Yes,they are two roots of $ x^2-(a+d)x+(ad-bc)=0$ .

Comment: Yes!  And can you see that one of them is positive?

Comment: Sure, because sum of them is a postitive.

Comment: Right!  And note that $y=(\lambda-a)x/b$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use the "brute force" approach here.  We have the matrix equation $Av=\lambda v$.  Thus, the eigenvalue equation becomes

$$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$

which implies that the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is zero.  Thus, we have

$$(\lambda -a)(\lambda -d)-bc=0$$

which implies that

$$\begin{align}
\lambda &=\frac{(d+a)\pm \sqrt{(d+a)^2-4(ad-bc)}}{2}\\
&=\frac{(d+a)\pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2+4bc}}{2}
\end{align}$$

Note that

$$y=\frac{\lambda -a}{b}x=\left(\frac{(d-a)\pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2+4bc}}{2}\right)x$$

Thus, for the positive-valued eigenvalue, $y$ is of the same sign as $x$, which means that there is one eigenvector for which $x>0$ and $y>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The approach of Mark Viola is probably the best for $2\times 2$ matrices. Note however that this generalizes to $n\times n$.

Indeed, the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices) states (in particular) that every positive matrix with positive elements has a unique positive eigenvector. Furthermore, the associated eigenvalue is the spectral radius of the matrix.